# MG-RAST API shows less files than site search

Tags: bioinformatics

MG-RAST site search shows almost 90 results
http://www.mg-rast.org/mgmain.html?mgpage=search&search=antarctica

while api search shows only 22
http://api.mg-rast.org/metagenome?country=Antarctica&limit=30

What am I doing wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that metagenome returns only records after march 2018.
The one should use http://api.mg-rast.org/search instead.